# ADO.NET with VB.NET - SELECT INTO query

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, ado.net

I have been successful with setting up a connection and retrieving information from my MS Access database to my Windows Form in Visual Studio using VB.NET and SELECT statements with some of the sample code below.

```
    Dim dataset As New DataSet

    Dim datatable As New DataTable
    dataset.Tables.Add(datatable)

    Dim data_adaptor As OleDbDataAdapter
    data_adaptor = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM test1", odbconnect)

    data_adaptor.Fill(datatable)
```

However when I set my DataAdaptor to a query like below, I have run into some trouble executing a SELECT INTO query.

```
    data_adaptor = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT first_name INTO newtable FROM test1", odbconnect)
```

I do not get any error but the table does not get created in the my access database.  I understand that I would have to redeclare or declare a new, Data Adaptor to actually get information from the newly created "newtable" but if I execute this, then open my Access Database, "newtable" does not exists.  However, if I run this query in Access, it works but I get a pop up box confirming that I want to paste data into a new table.  I imagine this could be a possible hang up with working with MS Access in this manner.  Is there some other setting or object I must use to execute a SELECT INTO query to create a new table?

Comment: Why do you copy the table?

Comment: Ultimately the tool that I will build will create data sets using Cartesian joins, so I will need to pull data from various tables existing in the database and merge all combinations into new tables to be exported to another application.

Comment: Okay, then i see why. Well, try Steve's suggestion. Good luck;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use a `OleDbDataAdapter` for this. Use simply a `OleDbCommand` and call `ExecuteNonQuery`

```
dbCmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT first_name INTO newtable FROM test1", odbconnect)
cbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```